# Why does $\Delta x$ approach to $0$ in the definition of derivation?

Tags: derivatives

In the definition of derivation, why $\Delta x$ approach to zero?
I searched, but couldn't find a convincing answer.

Comment: What level of understanding do you have about the derivative function?

Comment: The derivative tells us the slope of the tangent line at any point. We calculate the slope of the tangent line as the limit of the slope of secant lines. The secant lines approaches the tangent line as $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$

Comment: $\Delta x$ is a measure of the error in your approximation. You want it to go to zero because you would like to have no error.

Answer (score 0):

As Frog Will Do mentions, you take that limit because the slope of the tangent line is the slope of the secant line between points that get arbitrarily close together.

There are alternatives though without limits. A tangent line to a point on, say, a parabola, can be constructed using algebra. Likewise a tangent circle: [Derivatives without limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3197399/derivatives-without-limits)